# Map lsusb entru to /dev path

Tags: linux, docker, usb, high-availability, synology

This is driving me crazy. My usb device is recognized by my system because it shows in lsusb, but I cannot find to which /dev path is mapped. Please help.
See the image for my lsusb commad and /dev.
The device I want to find is 2-1 (Silicon Labs Sonoff Zigbee 3.0 USB Dongle Plus 0001)
[image]

Comment: What happened here?  Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got it figured out using tou help. In the end I was apparently missing the actual drivers which meant it was not showing up in /dev. After adding the correct drivers, it was mapped to /dev/ ttyUSB0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is on bus 2, and it is device 1, its path should be something like:

```
/dev/bus/usb/002/001
```

If it's not exactly that, just run `find /dev/bus/usb -type f` to see all the options for what it might be.  You might want to look in `/proc/bus` too, I forget the difference between those two paths.

P.S. Normally you don't need to know these paths because you can't do much with them.  Depending on what type of USB device you have, you might want to use libusb, hidapi, or a serial library to talk to it.